# How to check if current page link contains a certain string with react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

how can i check if my current page link contains a certain string and returns true or false?

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
               // Check if page link contains "/MYSTRING/xx"
               THEN DO THIS HERE..
        </Head>
      </Html>
    )
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you using in your project? ReactJS or React Native or NextJS?

Comment: I'm using NextJS.. im not sure how can i return a boolean if the link equal to the string..

Comment: You can refer to my answer below, and find more about next/router in NextJS, it manages all about the current link (pathname, query params,...) and navigation (moving from 1 page to another). Link: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:** Use `next/router` in NextJS  *(I recommend this)*

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  const { pathname } = useRouter()    

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
           // Check if page link contains "/MYSTRING/xx"
           {pathname?.includes('/MYSTRING/xx')
             ? `${pathname} includes '/MYSTRING/xx'`
             : `${pathname} doesn't include '/MYSTRING/xx'`
           }
        </Head>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

---

**Solution 2:** Use `window.location.href`

If using this way, you need to ensure that you are in client-side. Otherwise, you will saw error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

This is because in NextJS, when the page is loading, it runs the server-side first, but the object `window` is only existed in client-side. To detect whether you are on server or client, please check `typeof window === 'undefined'`. `true` is on server while `false` is on client.

However, it will lead to some case of miss match between server-rendered HTML and the client-render one, so I'm not prefer this approach.

You can play around in this [code demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zuvxqs?file=pages%2Findex.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page URL returned as a string with `window.location.href` and then check if the URL includes the string that you are looking for with the string [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method which returns a boolean.

**Solution**

```
const lookForThisString = 'someString'
window.location.href.includes(lookForThisString) // returns true or false
```

Comment: Its showing this error ( ReferenceError: window is not defined )

Comment: You saw the error because in NextJS, when the page is loading, it runs the server-side first, and object `window` is only existed in client-side. Therefore, you can check whether you are in client-side, then get the value from `window.location.href`.